# How to Search for a few words with a character that changes its position in the cell?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to figure out how to search to replace text containing a word, e.g: "This Is My Name!" that also may contain an extra character, in my case, the character "/".

So for example, I'd like to be able to use the search and replace functionality to match this sentence:

*This Is My Name! - blah blah / abc 123 ipsum*

As well as this sentence:

*ipsum lorem $999 - 3 / This Is My Name! $55*

Or this:

*ipsum lorem $999 - 3 / This Is My Name! $55 / Ipsum Lorem - (34)*

I'm assuming some form of regex?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Based on examples you have provided:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A3,"^This Is My Name!|/ This Is My Name!","SOMETHINGNEW"))
```

**Picture**
[image]

### Some explanation:

Regex is looking for

1. `^This Is My Name!`. `^` before your string means that text should start with your string
2. OR (this is represented by `|`)
3. `/ This Is My Name!` - which is your text and an extra character
4. `ArrayFormula` is added to populate formula down (in A1:A3) range

Helpful?